# Live Stream Metadata update CAF Receiver

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

How do i update the metadata in the receiver for live audio stream. Am using custom receiver but i don't find any methods for the same in the developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17897193)

Comment: @Shine I disagree - this is an actual answer. I can't speak to whether or not it's correct (I'm not familiar with that SDK), but that's a different issue. It's an answer whether it's correct or not, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I couldn't find anything until I stumble upon [setMediaInformation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/caf_receiver/cast.framework.PlayerManager.html#setMediaInformation), it works fine for now.

Answer (score -2):

Regarding to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cE0r9-dnns&feature=youtu.be&t=26m24s

It was schedule to be available in late 2017. So it should probably be coming soon. If someone from Google could confirm, that would be great !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18813867)

Comment: @Graham It does include the essential details

Comment: Please read the help section, specifically https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer as you are not providing any context to your link.  It doesn't matter what the link contains, it matters what your answer contains.

Comment: There is no way to do it currently and this is the only explanation. As explained, I would like to have the official answer from Google.